# Getting Dynamic firewall from Fedora 15 into Ubuntu?

Tags: firewall

Just tried out Fedora 15 and noticed the pre-installed firewall application that I found much easier to use than any other previously tried out firewall manager.

[image]

Definitely miss it at my Ubuntu workstation, so how can I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download it from [here](http://pkgs.org/package/firewalld).

Then you can use [Alien](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/alien) to convert it to a deb package. Run something like this at terminal:
`alien --to-deb package.rpm`

Finally install your package:
`sudo dpkg -i package.deb`

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Altough the package `firewall-applet` is also required to get the pretty GUI shown in my question. When firing it up it goes crazy with the below shown error, any ideas? `File "/usr/bin/firewall-applet", line 33, in <module>
    import firewall_client
  File "/usr/share/firewalld/firewall_client.py", line 21, in <module>
    import slip.dbus
ImportError: No module named slip.dbus
`

Comment: I think you will have to install this package too: pkgs.org/download/fedora-rawhide/fedora-i386/firewall-applet-0.1.3-2.fc16.noarch.rpm.html  I'm with my mobile right now, away from any computer, can't do any test until I get home.

Comment: You can compile the slip.dbus: 1) download the source http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/releases/15/Everything/source/SRPMS/python-slip-0.2.14-2.fc15.src.rpm 2) extract 3) open a terminal and cd to the directory 4) run this commands: ./configure && make && sudo make install