# Need a Firewall application similar to one that ships with Fedora

Tags: software-recommendation, firewall

I've used Ubuntu since more than a year now, as the Oneiric Ocelot has more than exceeded my expectations and provides most things out of the box. However, there is one feature that both Windows and Fedora provides - a network firewall that allows us to block specific incoming/outgoing ports such as HTTP(80), FTP(21), etc. I've seen it on Fedora17.

Since I'm going to learn some network programming, such a firewall will be very much useful for my development and testing.

Is there any such **equivalent** (and reliable) package in Ubuntu repository? I'm aware that I cannot fetch anything from the Fedora repo as they are in RPM formats, and also don't want to mess something with my Ubuntu deb packaging.

Comment: Exact Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/57237/getting-dynamic-firewall-from-fedora-15-into-ubuntu

Comment: Well, not an "exact" duplicate, as I am not too inclined to use the Fedora firewall, but am searching for an Ubuntu alternative instead.

Comment: +1 Understood, Just making you aware the question was there incase you found it useful. This line "Or can I install such software from somewhere else?"made me think you consider the fedora FW

Comment: `ufw` (see Rinzwind's answer), `gufw` (the gui version of UFW, needs GNOME runtime libs), or direct `iptables` commands are good ones.  `firestarter` is deprecated nowadays since it requires admin privileges to run, regardless of user, so that is dangerous.

Comment: It seems that ufw also needs admin privileges to run. What does it make different from firestarter? deprecated maybe... but risky? @Rinzwind said in the accepted answer: "How can you compare that!? A firewall either does what is does or it is not a firewall..." or is it that people MUST use ONLY what is supported by ubuntu? or even worst... what you say?

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo only to change things.  Firestarter was a GUI that *always* needed sudo in order to both view and modify the firewall.  ufw does require sudo, yes, but iptables is teh same way, and after wards, it closes down whatever you're running.  Every firewall needs admin privs, but Firestarter needs it just to load.  And if you close firestarter, the firewall settings get purged.  They never fixed that bug, and its been tehre for ages.

Comment: I can see you never used Firestarter in the right way. But ok. I used it and I yet use it and I have never experienced these issues you mention. But it's ok. Let's say it's ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [UFW - Uncomplicated Firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)

> The default firewall configuration tool for Ubuntu is ufw. Developed to ease iptables firewall configuration, ufw provides a user friendly way to create an IPv4 or IPv6 host-based firewall. By default UFW is disabled.
>
> Gufw is a GUI that is available as a frontend.

UFW is installed by default but inactve:

```
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Enable:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Disable:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

## Examples

```
sudo ufw allow /
sudo ufw allow 53
sudo ufw allow 53/tcp
sudo ufw allow 53/udp
sudo ufw deny /
sudo ufw deny 53
sudo ufw deny 53/tcp
sudo ufw deny 53/udp
```

[image]

More info in the 1st link.

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind. But is ufw as reliable and robust compared to the Fedora firewall which is based on RHEL? In this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/57237/getting-dynamic-firewall-from-fedora-15-into-ubuntu, the RHEL one seems to have several features such as masquerading, port-forwarding, ICMP filter, etc. whereas ufw just provides allow/deny.

Comment: Reliable? Yes, absolutely. Robust as Fedora? How can you compare that!? A firewall either does what is does or it is not a firewall...

Comment: They are both based on iptables, just frontends. Just try 'sudo iptables -L' to see exactly (no, there are more, but...) what they do. Yes, it's complicated. That is why there are such tools like ufw. If you tell us more specificly what to do, we could give you other suggestions.

Comment: @Anders What I exactly need is a GUI interface like that the windows provides, or one like Fedora/RHEL that I provided in the link. Just want to block incoming/outgoing ports without bothering about underlying iptables, etc. It would be preferable to also block specific programs from accessing certain networks (like Windows fw provides). But yes, presently I think ufw or Gufw can serve my purpose.

Comment: I added in an image. Makes it a bit more clear (from images on google the Fedora one looks rather nice :D )

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind, that looks pretty. Just out of curiosity, can I use gufw on debian too as ubuntu is debian based?

Comment: yes sir: http://packages.debian.org/sid/gufw @PrahladYeri

Answer (score 3):

The default firewall in Ubuntu is ufw - Uncomplicated Firewall. It is a command line tool, designed to be simpler than iptables, the common *nix firewall. A graphical version would be Gufw. You may install that by copying this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gufw
```

Note that ufw is disabled by default. ??! Maybe because only a few people really mess with the firewall rules? If you need more geeky features, you may use Firewall Builder. Not tried it myself, but the interface looks more complex...

```
sudo apt-get install fwbuilder
```

Comment: If you don't run servers, you don't need firewalls. As default desktop Ubuntu doesn't have any network servers running by default, there are no need for a firewall activated.
If you don't run a router, I can't see any use of more complicated rules than what ufw (and gufw) gives you.